# What is the determining component of a Mobile browser user-agent string in its HTML rendering variation?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Hi there I am trying to create a bug-free jquerymobile app across Android Browser, Dolphin, Mobile firefox, Opera Mini, + IOS4,5 (Safari).

I have Safari working well, the thing is I've based my conditionals on the IOS version and I am now worrying if that was the right thing to do. Maybe it shuold be based on the Safari version?

I also need to create some conditionals in my code for fixing the Bugs I've seen across default Android O.S versions 2.1,2.2,2.3.3,3.0,3.1,3.2,4.0.3.

Android 2.3.3 returns a user agent string of :

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-us; HTC Vision Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML; like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

Which component is the likely culprit causing the variation in HTML rendering? I.E which should I try run my conditionals off? Is it the AppleWebKit version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android browsers are shipped one per operating system version. So for example there is only one Android Browser for the Android 2.3.3 operating system.

That being said I would go for the browser version so you can normalize your conditionals with the other operating systems.

And **that** being said I would be careful of what you are doing. It sounds like it's going to be a nightmare to maintain your code. Perhaps you can write code that gracefully degrades without User-Agent sniffing.

Comment: Hi Jasper, thanks for your comment. Yes I agree, its one per O.S version and I should target the browser. What I need to know is which part of the browser in the user-agent reflects the HTML rendering engine version, which I can use as the basis for my comparator. Yes it does sound like a bit of a nightmare. I'm only going to use the conditionals for a small number of things, mainly fixing the footer placement in jquerymobile.

Comment: You want the `Webkit Version Number`. You should actually be able to search Google for the `Webkit Version Number` to find-out all kinds of quirks for the browser. Mobile Safari is just a skinned version of Webkit, so getting the Webkit version will help more. My point for Android was that `OS Version` == `Browser Version`, so you can check for either and get the same result as far as HTML rendering capabilities for the OS/Browser.

Comment: Hi Jasper, thanks for more info. Oh right OK there's a big point I missed there, so on Android you can't upgrade your default browser without upgrading the OS? I was assuming I'd have to cater to people who upgraded their browser as new releases came down the pipeline but didn't upgrade OS. Thanks that helps me a lot!!

Comment: Does anyone know if the browser only changes every main verison I.E Android 1.X --> 2.X --> 3.X , or can it change in minor updates?